# Mongodb query to retrieve data in month range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does anyone know how to retrieve data by month using Mongodb query? For example, if I only want to retrieve the date range for the past month, or for the past two month, how do I do that? I see examples for getting data for the last N day (e.g for past 5 days using this new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-5)  or N hours, but not seeing examples for only retrieving data for the last N month. Thanks,

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for such stuff - it makes your life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can retrieving data based on month like this.

`new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-1)` or `N` months.

And you can also get past month start and end date using moment like this.

```
moment().subtract(1,'months').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

it will provide previous month start date i.e `2021-01-01`

```
moment().subtract(1,'months').endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

it will provide previous month end date i.e `2021-01-31`

Comment: So it will be something like: $match: { 'CreateDate':  { $lt: new Date(), 
        $gte: new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-1)) }} ?

This doesn't seem to work as it gives me the data for the current month.

Comment: Yes it will find data of current month And if you want to find past month data then you need to search like this. new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-2)

Comment: Hmm, I tried $match: { 'CreateDate': { $lt: new Date(), $gte: new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-2)) }} and it returns me the data of this month, last month and even some data from Dec 31 last year. Still doesn't limit to only the last month's data.

Comment: I then tried $match: {'CreateDate':  { $lt:  new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-1)), 
        $gte: new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()-2)) }}, this time, it returns me the records from most Jan (last month) but also some data from Dec 31 last year. As now is Feb, I think the getMonth() just a way to automatically deduct 30 or 31 days instead of the real month. Any thoughts?

Comment: Today date new Date() is 2021-02-26T17:37:32.209Z
new Date(setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1)) this will provide you like this 2021-01-26T17:31:21.175Z
new Date(setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 2)) this will provide you like this 2020-12-26T17:31:46.762Z
CreatedDate gte new Date(setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 2)) i.e you will get date i.e gte  2020-12-26T17:31:46.762Z.

Comment: And you can also get past month start and end date using moment like this.

moment().subtract(1,'months').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

it will provide previous month start date i.e 2021-01-01

moment().subtract(1,'months').endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

it will provide previous month end date i.e 2021-01-31

Comment: @maitrythakkar - please edit your answer to provide the additional code snippets that are currently provided as comments. Very difficult to read as comments (also, given the number of comments, you might soon get an automated warning that this answer's comments are turning into a discussion). Also please be sure to properly format your text, for readability.

Comment: I think instead of `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` you should better use `.toDate()`

Comment: What is the full command to use moment() ? I tried moment().subtract(1,'months').startOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')  and it failed to execute as moment is not defined.

Comment: you need to import moment library in your project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment
npm i moment

and after that you need to defined moment in file which you used moment. i.e
const moment= require('moment') // define in your file.

Comment: I see so it is not a mongodb query command right?

Comment: Yes it's not mongodb query command. Actually it's javascript library that help in manipulating , validating date in very easy way.